# How to set DPI in Android VM?

Tags: android, virtualbox, dpi

How to set DPI (abstracted LCD density) in Android VM? It's just not working...

1. VirtualBox 4.1.10.
2. Android-x86-3.2-RC2-eeepc.iso (installed).
3. Parameters of the /mnt/grub/menu.lst file:

   quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot_hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode DPI=149 UVESA_MODE=1280x800 SRC=/android-2011-11-13

Whatever DPI value I have used - screen size does not changes.